# Small display issue in privacy-policy

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design, user-interface

There´s a small display issue with some subtext in the [privacy-policy](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/de/privacy-policy) on Careers Germany. This also applies to the [Careers UK](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/privacy-policy), [Careers Francais](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/privacy-policy) and [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/privacy-policy).

The [privacy-policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) on StackExchange has no display issues. So i think the others should match this style.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm - reproduced.

Comment: The text is overlapped. The font is very sharped.

Comment: Happens to me on the main Careers site as well; see screenshot below.

Comment: Confirmed, fix coming shortly.

Comment: @Max is it possible that the link to privacy-police on careers page should be updated. Currently it points to http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy, but it not should be http://careers.stackoverflow.com/privacy-policy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be an unfortunate combination of the following two CSS rules:

- `sub, sup { line-height: 0 }`, presumably intended to avoid sub/superscripts increasing the line spacing in text, and
- `.privacy-policy .tldr sub { display: block; }`, presumably intended as a kluge to force a line break before the "footnote".

The combined effect of these rules is that the "footnote" text is rendered as a separate paragraph with a zero line height, causing all the lines to overlap:

[image: Screenshot]

The simplest CSS fix I can think of would be to explicitly override the line height with:

```css
.privacy-policy .tldr sub { line-height: inherit }
```

That said, there are several other issues in the styling (starting with the `line-height: 0` kluge itself) that seem to me hacky and prone to further breakage.  It might be worth considering a more general review of those styles.

**Ps.** Yes, this fix is going into [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.12.

Comment: the privacy-policy on stackexchange has no display issues. so i think the others should look like that

Answer (score 3):

I've now updated the CSS (using Ilmari Karonen's suggested change).

Comment: Ilmari's paycheck is on its way? ;)